# Development environment for Angular2 contribution

Tags: angular

I'd like know the minimum development environment setup to start contributing to angular2.

I have

- node **6.6.0**
- npm **3.10.6**
- typescript **2.0.3**

Is there anything else I would need ?

Comment: why the downvotes? It's a legitimate doubt for any beginner willing to contribute to the open source angular framework

Comment: All you need is Git and the github url https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md to do pull requests :).

Comment: Thanks @NielsSteenbeek.

Comment: OP found what was needed at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#clang-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I posted the question prematurely without proper research.

Thanks to @NielsSteenbeek I've got exactly what I was looking for here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#clang-format

Here's an excerpt from the documentation (at the time of this writing):

> ### Prerequisite Software
>
> Before you can build and test Angular, you must install and configure the following products on your development machine:
>
> - [Git](http://git-scm.com) and/or the **GitHub app** (for [Mac](http://mac.github.com) or [Windows](http://windows.github.com)); [GitHub's Guide to Installing Git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) is a good source of information.
> - [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), (version `>=5.4.1 <6`) which is used to run a development web server,   run tests, and generate distributable files. We also use Node's Package Manager, `npm` (version `>=3.5.3 <4.0`), which comes with Node. Depending on your system, you can install Node either from   source or as a pre-packaged bundle.
> - [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which is used to execute the selenium standalone server for e2e testing.